# jQuery and chaining issue

Tags: jquery, chain

I'm a jQuery rookie and maybe I'm about to ask a very basic question, but I'm really struggling while figuring out why jQuery chaining doesn't work in my case.

```
var container = $('#container'),
items = container.find('ul.items'),
moreItems = items.children('li.moreItems');

var config = {
container : container,
items : items,
moreItems : moreItems
}

var app = myApp(config);

function MyApp(config) {
this.container = config.container;
this.items = config.items;
this.moreItems = config.moreItems;
this.current = 0;
}

MyApp.prototype.myUsefulFunction() {
this.moreItems[this.current].fadeIn();
}
```

Let's suppose I have a div#container filled with ul elements that have more than one li each. I'd like to access to the n-th li and fade the element in, but the console throws me back an error, stating fadeIn has no such method. Can you please help me sort it out?

Comment: Did you mean this instead? MyApp.prototype.myUsefulFunction = function() { this.moreItems[this.current].fadeIn(); }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery returns a jquery object, which is **a sort of array containing DOMELements**.

When you do: `this.moreItems[this.current]` you actually extract the DOMElement from the jquery array --> you have to turn it into a jquery object to be able to call fadeIn() !

```
$(this.moreItems[this.current]).fadeIn();
```

You can also use [.eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to filter the matched set to the only element corresponding to the index:

```
this.moreItems.eq(this.current).fadeIn();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/rfxVD/)**

---

Apart from that, the piece of code you show in your question has several syntax errors:

1. To add a function to the prototype, you should do:

   ```
   MyApp.prototype.myUsefulFunction = function() {}
   ```

   and not `MyApp.prototype.myUsefulFunction() {}`
2. Use the `new` operator to return a new instance of `MyApp`

   ```
   var app = new MyApp(config); // also spelling mistake: myApp != MyApp !!
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To make a jQuery method for chaining you need to extend jQuery.fn

```
$.fn.myUsefulFunction=function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();

    })
}
```

You can now use this as you would any other jQuery method

```
   $(selector).myUsefulFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Off-topic:

1. For create instance of class you need use **new**:

   var app = new myApp(config);
2. **myApp** and **MyApp** is a different variables.